# Parallel requests processing python + lambda

Tags: python, api, aws-lambda, python-requests

I have a list of around 800k IDs and for each ID I should sent a request to api, get data and insert into my database.

The current process is to loop each item and wait for hours :/

What is a smart way to perform this task using python + lambda?

Comment: How does Lambda factor into this? Are you running your loop in Lambda?

Comment: Yes. It was build running on aws lambda. So I was looking for a "smart" solution to use aws lambda and python paralleling the processing

Answer (score 1):

You can use **concurrent.futures** that allows parallelized processes in python:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Define your worker function:

```py
import time

def worker(id):
    print(f"start worker {id}")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"end worker {id}")
```

Parallelize:

```py
currs = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) # If you don't want more than 5 parallelized execution of your function

for i in range(20): # Assuming you want to submit 20 requests
    curr_future_result = currs.submit(worker, i)
```

If you want to perform api calls you can do something like:

```py
import requests

urls = [.......]

def worker(url):
    requests.get(url)
    
currs = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

for url in urls:
    curr_future_result = currs.submit(worker, url)
```

Comment: The preferred way would be the `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures` high-level constructs. If you use raw `threading`, you'll need to manage job queueing (800k threads is not a good idea) and error management, etc. yourself.

Comment: I was not suggesting to parallelize 800K threads at a same time. Grouping them like 10 by 10 could definitly improve the database load time.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what those higher-level modules do for you.

Comment: Updated with futures :)